# How inject new implementation of a SDK interface?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I am using Atlassian SDK to create a plugin. In this SDK there is an interface and its implementation which is used to fetch some data about editors. I have created a new implementation on this interface and I want to inject it to my other classes. But when I define `@Component` or `@Named` I got a lot of error about Thread and Runnable.

My question is that is it possible to inject another implementation of an interface which you have not any access to it and its default implementation codes(In the SDK). If yes am I do correctly? Or can I solve it by extending my implantation from default implementation?

```
@ExperimentalApi
public interface FieldHtmlFactory {
    List<FieldHtmlBean> getCreateFields(ApplicationUser var1, OperationContext var2, Action var3, MutableIssue var4, boolean var5, List<String> var6);

    List<FieldHtmlBean> getLinkedIssueCreateFields(ApplicationUser var1, OperationContext var2, Action var3, MutableIssue var4, Issue var5, boolean var6, List<String> var7);

    List<FieldHtmlBean> getEditFields(ApplicationUser var1, OperationContext var2, Action var3, Issue var4, boolean var5);

    List<FieldHtmlBean> getInlineEditFields(ApplicationUser var1, OperationContext var2, Action var3, Issue var4, boolean var5);

    List<FieldHtmlBean> getSubTaskCreateFields(ApplicationUser var1, OperationContext var2, Action var3, MutableIssue var4, boolean var5, List<String> var6);
}
```

default implementation:(without any annotation)

```
public class FieldHtmlFactoryImpl implements FieldHtmlFactory {...}
```

My implementation:

```
@Scanned
@Named("editorImpl")
public class FieldEditorFactoryImpl implements FieldHtmlFactory { ... }
```

Where I want to use:

```
@Scanned
@Path("/table")
public class TableREST {

    @Inject
    @Named("editorImpl")
    private final FieldHtmlFactory fieldEditorFactoryImpl;

    @Autowired
    public TableREST(FieldHtmlFactory editorImp){
        this.editorImp = editorImp;
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it. For whom may need its solution I want put the my way...

I extended my class from the default implementation(instead of implement the interface). Then I could define Named annotation to it.

```
@Named("FieldEditorFactoryImpl")
public class FieldEditorFactoryImpl extends FieldHtmlFactoryImpl {

    public FieldEditorFactoryImpl(BeanFactory beanFactory, FieldManager fieldManager, FieldScreenRendererFactory fieldScreenRendererFactory, PermissionManager permissionManager) {
        super(beanFactory, fieldManager, fieldScreenRendererFactory, permissionManager);
    }

    public String sayHelloWorld(){
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}

@Scanned
@Path("/table")
public class TableREST {

    private FieldEditorFactoryImpl fieldEditorFactoryImpl;

    @Autowired
    public TableREST(@Named("FieldEditorFactoryImpl") FieldHtmlFactory fieldHtmlFactory){
        this.fieldEditorFactoryImpl = (FieldEditorFactoryImpl) fieldHtmlFactory;
    }

    ...
}
```